# Styled components not overriding styles from another component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, styled-components

I have a component that is already built out like so:

```
const Banner = ({ image, heading, text }) => (
  <Container>
    <Background src={image}>
      <BannerContent>
        <h1>{heading}</h1>
        <h2>{text}</h2>
      </BannerContent>
    </Background>
  </Container>
);

const BannerContent = styled.div`
  h1 {
    font-size: 24px;
  }

  h2 {
    font-size: 16px;
  }
`;
```

and I'm trying to override the styles of the `h1` and `h2` and add new styles like so in another component:

```
const PageBanner = styled(Banner)`
  h1 {
    font-size: 20px;
    width: ...
  }

  h2 {
    font-size: 13px;
    width: ...
  }
`;
```

However, none of that is happening. I'm assuming it's because it's nested in there? Am I able to override the styles? Or should I just build a similar component to it?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

If you are styling one of your own custom components, you must make sure you use the [`className` prop that styled components gives to the component](https://www.styled-components.com/docs/advanced#styling-normal-react-components).

```
const Banner = ({ image, heading, text, className }) => (
  <Container className={className}>
    <Background src={image}>
      <BannerContent>
        <h1>{heading}</h1>
        <h2>{text}</h2>
      </BannerContent>
    </Background>
  </Container>
);

const PageBanner = styled(Banner)`
  h1 {
    font-size: 20px;
    width: ...
  }

  h2 {
    font-size: 13px;
    width: ...
  }
`;
```

Comment: Does that mean I have to pass in a class name in `PageBanner`? Something like `<PageBanner className="name"` and style the class name under `PageBanner`?

Comment: @Spacebear5000 No, it just means that styled components will create a new class name under the hood and send that to the wrapped `Banner` component. You just have to make sure that you are using this `className` prop that is given to the `Banner` component.

Comment: I've lost **so** much time on this, I even read that part of the documentation and didn't really get it. Albeit, I'm just starting to learn React, so _thank you_, @Tholle!

Comment: For anyone using React Native, the same concept applies but the prop to use is `style` instead of `className`.

Comment: This is simply amazing!